# Add UIPickerView in UIActionSheet from IOS 8 not working

Tags: ios, iphone, uipickerview, uiactionsheet, ios8

I am adding `UIPickerView` to `UIActionsheet` but its working perfectally in `ios 7` but not working in `ios 8`. Please help me to solve that.

Here i attached screenshot for that.[image]

Thanks

I am using following code for that.

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet;
NSString *pickerType;

- (void)createActionSheet {

    if (actionSheet == nil) {
        // setup actionsheet to contain the UIPicker
        actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please select" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
        actionSheet.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
        pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
        [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];

        UIImageView *imageObj = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
        imageObj.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"];
        [pickerToolbar addSubview:imageObj];

        UIButton *cancelBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [cancelBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerCancel:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        // [cancelBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnInviteCancel.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cancelBtn setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        cancelBtn.frame = CGRectMake(7.0, 7.0, 65.0, 25.0);
        [pickerToolbar addSubview:cancelBtn];

        UIButton *doneBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [doneBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerDone:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        //[doneBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnInviteDone.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [doneBtn setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        doneBtn.frame = CGRectMake(258.0, 7.0, 55.0, 25.0);
        [pickerToolbar addSubview:doneBtn];

        [actionSheet addSubview:pickerToolbar];
        [pickerToolbar release];


        UIPickerView *chPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 200.0)];
        chPicker.dataSource = self;
        chPicker.delegate = self;
        chPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
        [chPicker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
        [actionSheet addSubview:chPicker];
        [chPicker release];

        [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
        [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 464)];
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe it would be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629113/change-font-type-and-size-of-uiactionsheet-title-string/11629411#11629411

Answer (score 21):

Per the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiactionsheet_class/index.html),

> **Important**: `UIActionSheet` is deprecated in iOS 8. (Note that `UIActionSheetDelegate` is also deprecated.) To create and manage action sheets in iOS 8 and later, instead use `UIAlertController` with a `preferredStyle` of `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet`.

[Link to documentation for UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertController_class/)

For example:

```
     UIAlertController * searchActionSheet=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

                [ searchActionSheet.view setBounds:CGRectMake(7, 180, self.view.frame.size.width, 470)];

                //yourView represent the view that contains UIPickerView and toolbar
                [searchActionSheet.view addSubview:self.yourView];
                [self presentViewController:searchActionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: grrr, did they have to break the old? Seems this is the new direction using actions and alertStyle.

Comment: did you try this? addSubview does not seem to work with UIAlertController.

Comment: I tried a different direction, which led to a new question. Perhaps you have some insight. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25975974/ios-8-broke-uipickerview-in-uiactionsheet

Comment: I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using addSubview

Comment: Can I see your code and the exception line . And do you deploy on iOS 8 .

Answer (score 20):

It doesn't work because Apple changed internal implementation of `UIActionSheet`. Please refer to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiactionsheet_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Subclassing Notes
>
> UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, **nor**
>   **should you add views to its hierarchy**. If you need to present a sheet with more customization than provided by the UIActionSheet API, you can create your own and present it modally with presentViewController:animated:completion:.

Comment: But presentViewController only displays a full screen view controller modally - how do we make it look similar to a UIActionsheet?

Comment: You are totally right. It looks like Apple now make sure that no one can abuse this component. I've debug the `UIActionSheet` and currently it is a fake `UIView` and plays a role of proxy object. It doesn't have any `subviews` and doesn't have a `superview` `drawRect:` and  `layoutSubviews` is never called even  when it is visible. So any visual manipulation on `UIActionSheet` will always fail and there is no simple workaround for it. Same issue applies for `UIAlertView`.

Answer (score 8):

I found this problem too and I have a solution, I hope it can help you..

You can download the sample code here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yrzq3hg66pjwjwn/UIPickerViewForIos8.zip?dl=0

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>{
    UIView *maskView;
    UIPickerView *_providerPickerView;
    UIToolbar *_providerToolbar;
}


- (void) createPickerView {
    maskView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    [maskView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5]];

    [self.view addSubview:maskView];
    _providerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 344, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];

    UIBarButtonItem *done = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet:)];
    _providerToolbar.items = @[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil], done];
    _providerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [self.view addSubview:_providerToolbar];

    _providerPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 300, 0, 0)];
    _providerPickerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.5];
    _providerPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    _providerPickerView.dataSource = self;
    _providerPickerView.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:_providerPickerView];
}

- (void)dismissActionSheet:(id)sender{
    [maskView removeFromSuperview];
    [_providerPickerView removeFromSuperview];
    [_providerToolbar removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't show anything because uiactionsheet & uiactionsheetdelegate is deprecated is ios8  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/index.html

You need to use UIAlertController in ios 8.

Comment: Deprecated does not mean deleted. UIActionSheet works fine in iOS 8

Comment: Actually, they don't work properly in iOS8+.  If you have the onscreen keyboard visible, then the keyboard will appear *on top of* your UIActionSheet, so you won't be able to see your action sheet options !!  You'll just see the screen go dark.

Comment: @MikeGledhill you need send resignFirstResponder message to your keyboard before actionsheet will be shown

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work.  The keyboard just stayed on the screen. What DID work was adding this line of code:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061964/uiactionsheet-not-showing-in-ios-8/35334974#35334974

Comment: @MikeGledhill thanks, I got you, I check it later bro)

Answer (score -2):

```
actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                                         destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this when presenting UIActionSheet in last 2 lines:

```
[actionSheet showFromRect:CGRectMake(0,480, 320,215) inView:self.view animated:YES];
[actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 464)];
```