# UIPickerView is not showing and CLLocationManager is not working in iOS 8

Tags: xcode, ios8, uipickerview, xcode6, cllocationmanager

I want to my already build app work on iOS 8, so I install Xcode 6.0 and run my app into iOS 8 it is showing me few issues.

- Picker view's values are not showing `UIPickerView` in iOS 8.
- Location `CLLocationManager` is not working in iOS 8.

Kindly help me on these if some body faced these issues already. Looking for response.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 8 you need 2 parts to get permission for CLLocationManager.

Provide one of the following strings in the info.plist file

- NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
- NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

Call the appropriate permission method in code which matches the string above

- requestAlwaysAuthorization
- requestWhenInUseAuthorization

Comment: Thanks I also got help location from other's thread but not getting for Picker view so is there possible for any solution.

Comment: @josh for the UIPickerView, it is due to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24366437/add-uipickerview-in-uiactionsheet-from-ios-8-not-working