# UIPickerView Only Responds Within Area of Tab Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, uialertcontroller

I'm updating my app to iOS 8 and trying to recreate the `UIPickerView` inside a `UIActionSheet` with `UIAlertController` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24366437/add-uipickerview-in-uiactionsheet-from-ios-8-not-working). Using the answer from Nada Gamal, I was able to recreate the functionality, but the `UIPickerView` only responds within the tab bar (even though the tab bar is hidden behind the picker view). The tab bar controller is the root view controller.

```
-(void)loadPickerView{
    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [pickerView selectRow:pickerViewRow inComponent:0 animated:NO];

    UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
    pickerToolbar.tintColor = self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor;

    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet)];
    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];

    [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];

    UIAlertController * searchActionSheet=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    [ searchActionSheet.view setBounds:CGRectMake(8, 208, self.view.frame.size.width, pickerView.frame.size.height+pickerToolbar.frame.size.height)];

    [searchActionSheet.view addSubview:pickerToolbar];
    [searchActionSheet.view addSubview:pickerView];
    [self presentViewController:searchActionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The `presentViewController` in the last line seems to be the issue. I've tried many different ways to get the pickerView to respond outside the tab bar area, including:

- `self`
- `self.tabBarController`
- `self.navigationController` (pickerView doesn't show up at all)
- `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController`

The other option is to make a separate view controller for this, but I'm concerned that won't work either because `UIAlertController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, but perhaps this is an issue with adding subviews to `UIAlertController`.